# Xcode8 cannot connect multiple/single uibuttons to single @IBAction in swift file

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, swift3, xcode8

I am using Xcode 8 beta. I cannot drag multiple UIButtons from storyboard to connect to a single @IBAction in swift file. Bug? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**By Using this workaround you can add existing action and also can connect multiple buttons to a single action.**

I think there is a bug in Xcode8. You can add multiple/Single button to a single action /function by changing `sender` to `_ sender`

eg :- Normal Button

```
   @IBAction func huu(sender: UIButton) {

   }
```

You can't add multiple buttons or single button to this action you need to simply change like this and then you can add multiple buttons by using drag and connect from storyboard.

```
 @IBAction func huu(_ sender: UIButton) {

 }
```

After connecting IBOutlets Xcode will show a warning like this :-

[image]

To remove this warning simple delete `_` sign from the action/function. Make sure that to delete `_` after connecting your IBOutlets

Hope that this will gonna help you! :)

Comment: This is a great answer and works with the release version of Xcode 8. Thanks! Another idea is to remove the argument completely.

Comment: @ Chathuranga Silva - It worked for me, thanks. @ Daniel T that also worked, thanks.

Comment: It works... It saddens me that we're going at those length to use a stable version of Xcode nowadays...

Comment: Awesome workaround but Apple should acknowledge this bug.

Comment: My action had "_ sender" by default, but changing "Any" to "UIButton" worked for me.

Answer (score 13):

If you change the sender to **AnyObject** as opposed to Any or **UIButton** it will allow you to connect multiple buttons to the same action.

Comment: This works. I change to `AnyObject` and it works. Apparently, it's a bug in Xcode 8.2.1 .

Answer (score 10):

When you connect a button action, by default the method will looks like :

```
@IBAction func s(_ sender: Any) {
    }
```

Just change **Any** to **UIButton** and you can connect more button actions to this particular method.

So after changing it should looks like this :

```
@IBAction func s(_ sender: UIButton) {
    }
```

Hope this will solve the issue. :)

Comment: This one did it for me too!

Answer (score 4):

If you change "Any" to "UIButton" it will work.

Answer (score 1):

If I am correct you need to use `UIGestureRecognizer` to attach multiple things to one action.

What you could do is place a `UIGestureRecognizer` on each button, and then setup one of them like you normally would with a button (ctrl-drag), than ctrl-drag from the other gesture recognizers to the first action you made.

Comment: Thanks for prompt response. I believe that would work as well. However, in the previous version of XCode, you can just ctrl-drag multiple buttons directly to one IBAction. With xcode 8 beta, I can no longer do that. I ended up just manually connecting it via the the connection inspector.

Answer (score 1):

The Below IBAction will work only for one Button.

```
@IBAction func singleButton(sender: Any) {
   // Write your logic
}
```

The Below IBAction will work with multiple buttons.

```
@IBAction func multipleButton(sender: UIButton) {
   // To find a particular button from an array of buttons
   if sender.tag == 1{
     // Write your logic
   }else if sender.tag == 2{
    // Write your logic
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's another issue : if you try to create an IBAction the first time, it works fine.
But if for any reason you decide to re-connect the IBAction (same action to another object, or rename the function), then it fails.

In fact, you create an IBAction called `doSomething`, which creates a function `func doSomething(sender: UIButton)`.
But with XCode 8 (or Swift 2.3 / 3.0), this method is interpreted as `func doSomethingWithSender(sender: UIButton)`.

I guess it's a bug, Apple went a bit too hard on the "rename Objc-methods" thing.

Comment: Have you found any solution for this?

Comment: No, it's obviously a problem in Xcode. Either Apple fixes this, or you convert your code to Swift 3.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the sender to UIButton from Any

Control drag the button to the name of the function.

Answer (score 0):

IN Swift 3 full version this will work.

Just change Any to UIButton and you can connect more button actions to this particular method.

So after changing it should looks like this :

@IBAction func s(_ sender: UIButton) {
    }
Sure this will solve the issue. :)

Answer (score 0):

I tried many times, at last, i got the result as,

Normal UIAction

```
@IBAction func selectBtn(_ sender: Any) {

   }
```

for Multiple Buttons with same UIAction method, try below method,

```
@IBAction func selectBtn(_ sender: UIButton) {

   }
```

This worked for me. I changed the return type from "Any" to "UIButton"