# How to connect multiple buttons in a storyboard to a single action in Swift 3 to increment value?

Tags: button, action, increment, swift3

I have four buttons that I want the user to press.  The button values are 1, 5, 25, and 100.

I have a label set up to show the total of all the values of the buttons pressed.

However, the numbers are not adding up because of where I have the equation within the code for the IBAction buttons.  I saw in prior posts that there used to a 'connect action', that would be able to connect multiple IBAction buttons in a storyboard to a signle action with Swift.  I cannot locate that feature in Swift 3.

So, how can I connect mulitple IBActions buttons within a storyboard to a single action within Swift 3?

The following code is placed after

```
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

var oneButtonTapped = 0
var noButtonTapped = 0
@IBAction func oneButtonTapped(_ sender: AnyObject) {oneButtonTapped = oneButtonTapped + 1

//Aware that the location of the code is requiring the 1 button to be tapped to be update.  TODO: Have the total update after every button tap

    let totalAmount = (noButtonTapped + oneButtonTapped + fiveButtonTapped + twentyfiveButtonTapped + hundredButtonTapped)

    Amount.text = String(totalAmount)
}
var fiveButtonTapped = 0
@IBAction func fiveButtonTapped(_ sender: AnyObject) {fiveButtonTapped = fiveButtonTapped + 5
}
var twentyfiveButtonTapped = 0
@IBAction func twentyfiveButtonTapped(_ sender: AnyObject) {twentyfiveButtonTapped = twentyfiveButtonTapped + 25
}
var hundredButtonTapped = 0
@IBAction func hundredButtonTapped(_ sender: AnyObject) {hundredButtonTapped = hundredButtonTapped + 100
}
```

Thank you in advance for your assistance, it is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

this looks pretty similar to this thread [Connecting Multiple Buttons to a single IBAction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37845914/xcode8-cannot-connect-multiple-single-uibuttons-to-single-ibaction-in-swift-fil). Basically you can use Autolayout's connection tool to "control drag" multiple buttons from the story board to a previously created IBAction in your swift code.

This Link [Can multiple buttons be connected to a single IBAction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40353024/can-multiple-buttons-be-attached-to-a-single-ibaction-is-xcode-8) has some animated GIFs that show the connection process.

You can then refer to the button that triggers the code using the "sender" parameter.

Just as an aside it looks as though your code is sitting inside the didReceiveMemoryWarning() function.

Hope this helps.