# can multiple buttons be attached to a single IBAction is Xcode 8?

Tags: ios, xcode8, ibaction

I have tried to connect several buttons to a single IBAction in Xcode 8 however it does not work. I tried the practices outlined here [Xcode8 cannot connect multiple/single uibuttons to single @IBAction in swift file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37845914/xcode8-cannot-connect-multiple-single-uibuttons-to-single-ibaction-in-swift-fil) still to no avail. can anyone shed some light as to why or if it is simply still just a bug?

Comment: Some times interface builder behaves weirdly.  Try ctrl+dragging from your code to the document outline in interface builder.  I find this works much better.

Comment: I've found ctrl+drag being flakey can often by resolved with command+k or option+command+k

Answer (score 4):

Works fine for me in Xcode 8.1 on a new Swift 3 project. You have to control-drag from the button to the center side of the method to select it if it already exists rather than drag to the left side.

[image]

Comment: thank you! Do you think syntax would affect it at all? I'm using 2.3 still

Comment: I don't know. Wouldn't shock me. I added an animated GIF to show you what I did.

Comment: is there a reason your action appears with the underscore, mine merely appears with sender. Not sure if this makes a difference I was just curious

Comment: Yes, I think that would matter. The first parameter should have an underscore because it is unnamed. I'm not sure it is used in Swift 2.3, though - I started with Swift 3.

Comment: I was able to resolve the issue by updating to 8.1 and using the underscore syntax so thank you for your assistance

Answer (score 2):

change your parameter from (_ sender: **Any**) to (_ sender: **UIButton**), and you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason why several buttons should not connect to a single action function in your code. I had no trouble doing this when I tried it, as you can see:

[image]

However, if the nib editor interface won't let you form the connection, configure the action-target of the buttons in code.

Answer (score 0):

Double check if you want to add action to a real button
Check if when you wrote the action, you used some customized class instead of UIButton, and the class of your button does not match.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue by upgrading to Xcode 8.1 and including an _ before the sender argument. I believe this is just a bug from Xcode 8 because I tried the latter before upgrading and I was still unable to connect.